# Xamarin Android with Azure SQL Database and SignalR

Tags: android, sql, azure, xamarin, signalr

I am building a chat app for my University library, and have run into some hurdles. The technologies I am using are Xamarin Android and Microsoft Azure. The issue I have is that I don't know how to connect my Xamarin Android app to my Azure SQL database. I need the database for a couple of reasons:

1) Authenticating my users to ensure only our University students can log in.
2) For the list of topics that the library may wish to put up for the students.

I will also be needing to use SignalR for the chat capabilities.

Now on Azure I have created a Web+Mobile app, which has given me a URL for the app, and I have created an SQL database, which has given me connection info for the database.

How do I connect my mobile app to the database, so I can perform my CRUD operations? I have gone through the documentation on Xamarin like "Consuming a RESTful web service" but unfortunately am still needing to find the solution.

Thanks and Regards,

Aditya Johar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I connect my mobile app to the database, so I can perform my CRUD operations?

You could create a Web API for validating login users and CRUD operations, and you could use ADO.NET objects (SqlConnection, SqlCommand etc) or Entity Framework to work with your Azure SQL database. And then you could use HttpClient to send request to Web API to validate login user and do CRUD operations from Xamarin Android app.

[Example: CRUD ASP.NET Web API With Entity Framework](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-Asp-Net-web-api-with-entity-framework-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)

[Xamarin Android: Create Login With WEB API Using Azure SQL Server](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-with-web-api-using-azure-sql-server-part-two/)

> I will also be needing to use SignalR for the chat capabilities.

You need to create hub class and define hub methods that clients can call, and then you could start the hub connection and invoke methods on the hub server in your Xamarin Client. The following articles would be helpful.

[ASP.NET SignalR Xamarin Client](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signalr)

[ASP.NET SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)